# Define class parameters to be called, when my class is executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to define a class parameter to be called when my class below is called.

I run my class via `scrapy runspider script.py`

My class looks like:

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, site_search_url):
        self.site_search_url = site_search_url

    base = 'http://www.website.com/search?q=site:'
    start_urls = [base + self.site_search_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        #parse attributes here.
```

Specifically, I want to require `site_url` class-level parameter be set when `BrickSetSpider()` is executed.

**update** Im running this like `scrapy runspider script.py -a site_search_url=domain.com` but its failing on:

```
start_urls = [base + self.site_search_url]
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Why is this not setting the value?

Comment: Read up on `__init__` function

Comment: How can I pass this value to the class upon calling my python script though via scrapy?

Comment: Im including my __init__ above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by defining an `__init__` function and overriding ____.

Here's what the final code looks like:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def __init__(self, site_search_url):
        self.site_search_url = site_search_url

    def start_requests(self):
        base = 'http://www.example2.com/'
        start_urls = [
            'http://www.example.com/1.html',
            'http://www.example.com/2.html',
            'http://www.example.com/3.html',
            base + self.site_search_url,
        ]
        for url in start_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
```

You can then call it like so:

```
scrapy runspider script.py -a url='abc' myscript.py
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. however how do i set it upon calling my script like im  currently doing: `scrapy runspider script.py`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt appear to be setting it? Can you look at **update** above?

Comment: @Jshee, you need to refer to it as `self.site_search_url` instead of `site_search_url` directly in `start_urls = [base + site_search_url]`, also your `__init__` function says `site_url` instead of `site_search_url`. Please fix those errors and try again.

Comment: I tried again, and got the  same error. my code is updated above. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jshee, the error you posted no longer matches the code you've posted. What's the new error you get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134930/discussion-between-ffledgling-and-jshee).